# Android CardView layout broken pre-API 28

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I have view layout using a `CardView` that is supposed to look like this

[image]

And it looks fine on devices running Android 9 and above (API 28+). However, on anything older it looks to be broken:

[image]

The layout is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="165dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:contentPadding="8dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab_title"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="Sample User"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tab_close"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm using the `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'` dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was the value set for `cardCornerRadius`. Setting it to 20dp got me the desired border-radius without breaking the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`SDP`**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) - a scalable size unit

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

**FYI**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="125dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  app:cardCornerRadius="165dp"
  app:cardElevation="8dp"
  app:contentPadding="8dp"
  >
```

Leads to inconsistency. Different layouts end up hard-coding different font sizes and margins, making the app appear less polished.

**TRY**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_125sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_150sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    >
     .........
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_22sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_22sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                >
```

**NOTE**

Switch to [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

> AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in
> the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names
> changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

**Like**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```